# Dynamically drag down notification area in Android

Tags: android, animation, notifications

I have this Activity that hides the status bar (full screen) but I would like to give the user the ability to show the notification area at any point. Is there a way to tell Android to show the notification area from code, you know, with the fancy pull down animation and everything, even though the status bar is not showing? I have looked into [NotificationManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html) and all of the Notification api's but haven't found anything. Starting to doubt there is a way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can add this code to wherever you want it to execute

```
    Object sbservice = getSystemService( "statusbar" );
    Class<?> statusbarManager = Class.forName( "android.app.StatusBarManager" );
    Method showsb = statusbarManager.getMethod( "expand" );
    showsb.invoke( sbservice );
```

And add this permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.EXPAND_STATUS_BAR" />
```

Comment: This worked wonderfully, but why the nastiness with reflection? Why can't I find a reference to the StatusBarManager class directly? Why is there not a constant in the Context class for the "statusbar" service? I'm confused?

Comment: I didn't knew the answer so I asked a question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11323637/why-cant-i-find-a-reference-to-the-statusbarmanager-class-directly , lets see what answers we get.