# Why can't I find a reference to the StatusBarManager class directly?

Tags: android, statusbar

To dynamically drag down notification area in Android, the only solution is this

```
    Object sbservice = getSystemService( "statusbar" );
    Class<?> statusbarManager = Class.forName( "android.app.StatusBarManager" );
    Method showsb = statusbarManager.getMethod( "expand" );
    showsb.invoke( sbservice );
```

This works wonderfully, but why the nastiness with reflection? Why can't I find a reference to the StatusBarManager class directly? Why is there not a constant in the Context class for the "statusbar" service?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> why the nastiness with reflection?

Because it is not part of the Android SDK. Only people interested in creating unreliable apps would try to interact with the `StatusBarManager` outside of the Android source code itself, since the core Android team and device manufacturers are welcome to change anything outside of the SDK whenever they wish.

> Why can't I find a reference to the StatusBarManager class directly?

Because it is not part of the Android SDK. There are a great many classes and methods in Android framework classes that are marked with the `@hide` annotation, for all sorts of reasons: unwillingness to commit to support the API indefinitely, "security by obscurity", etc.

> Why is there not a constant in the Context class for the "statusbar" service?

Because it is not part of the Android SDK. You are certainly welcome to supply patches to the AOSP to have `StatusBarManager` be "promoted" to the same status as the other system services (e.g., `LocationManager`, `NotificationManager`). If the `StatusBarManager` situation is merely an oversight after the SDK was created in ~2007, your patches might well be accepted and you would see the change in an upcoming version of Android.

Answer (score 1):

For those hoping to use this API directly with their system app (like me), there's a way to get access without reflection.

Add this to your app's `Android.mk`:

```
LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := platform
LOCAL_PRIVILEGED_MODULE := true
```