# statusbar class reflection

Tags: java, android, reflection, android-statusbar

I'm trying to get this piece of code put right but the "statusbar" word gets underlined with a huge message telling me that I must use one of the following provided keywords.

Image of what I have in android studio editor:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJaan.png)

I want to get somehow access to the statusbarManager to disable expansion.

Is there a workaround?

Here is my code:

```
       try{
        Object sbservice = getSystemService( "statusbar" );
        Class<?> statusbarManager = Class.forName("android.app.StatusBarManager");
        Method showsb = statusbarManager.getMethod( "expand" );
        showsb.invoke(sbservice)
    }catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
    {e.printStackTrace();}
    catch (NoSuchMethodException e)
    {e.printStackTrace();}
    catch(IllegalAccessException e)
    {e.printStackTrace();}
    catch (InvocationTargetException e)
    {e.printStackTrace();}
```

Comment: 1. It's pretty clear that there is no such service that you are trying to get. Refer available services here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context. 2. Why are you doing this? What do you need the reflection for?

Comment: 1. This is what I found: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11323637/why-cant-i-find-a-reference-to-the-statusbarmanager-class-directly
2. I need to prevent the statusbar from being able to pulled down. AND NO, the fullscreen mode does not prevent this from happening. I have been searching for days and the only way to get access to the statusbarmanager is through reflection. Once you have access you can call the method to disable the expansion.

Comment: You can probably suppress that. Put your cursor on the error, hit alt+enter, and look for one of the Suppress options. Just FYI, that's likely not going to work at all, starting with Android P, as they're locking down on using reflection for things like that.

Comment: @Mike M. - thank you for your answer. Do you think that by rooting the tablet could achieve same thing somehow? If so, can you link me a guidance or something where I can start searching at?

Comment: I have no idea. I've never tried to disable that before.